# Dynamic Content Editor

Tags: content, users, management

I've asked this question around the net and still haven't found exactly what I'm looking for. Basically I have several sites that I run through a custom PHP framework. I'd like to add a way for users to content management but all I really want is a simple interface that lets users click and edit (similar to Concrete5).

All they really need is.. well, pretty much what I'm writing this with. A way to format text. All of the links/framework, that sort of thing are taken care of by me or automated through scripting.

Is there a good foundation to build on? It seems a little unnecessary to re-build everything into a CMS like Wordpress or Concrete. I know exactly what's in my programming, I'd rather use it. I just want an easy way for clients to edit content.

Comment: Although it could be considered a 'shopping list' question, I think this is a valuable resource and should be locked, not closed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds to me your after a Inline WYSIWYG Editor, there happens to be many on the market that you can integrate into your current setup. Of course a content management system is better if you want to allow more than yourself using the engine.

Here's just a few to get you started:

1. [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/)
2. [TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/)
3. [Aloha Editor](http://aloha-editor.org/)
4. [NicEdit](http://nicedit.com/)
5. [Snippetedit](http://www.snippetedit.com/)
6. [Wymeditor](http://www.wymeditor.org/)
7. [PimenTech-scripts : jquery.jframe.js](http://garage.pimentech.net/scripts_doc_jquery_jframe/)
8. [Jeditable](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable)
9. [jQuery Editable](http://www.dyve.net/jquery/?editable)
10. [Edit in Place With Ajax Using jQuery JavaScript](http://15daysofjquery.com/edit-in-place-with-ajax-using-jquery-javascript-library/15/)
11. [Table Editor](http://dev.iceburg.net/jquery/tableEditor/demo.php) (Useful for Editable Tables)
12. [jQuery Plugin: Inline Text Edit](http://www.codenothing.com/archives/2009/inline-text-edit/)
13. [Ajax Instant Edit](http://www.yvoschaap.com/instantedit/)
14. [JeIP](http://josephscott.org/code/javascript/jeip-demo/)

Comment: 1, 3, and 13 seem like the best ones. I'll probably go with 13 for this project but thanks for the selection. (btw, 9 says it's outdated and to use 8 instead)

Comment: #1 and #2 seem to be the most robust and popular. WordPress uses #2 by default and Drupal 8 just settled to use #1 in its upcoming release.