# Web-based interface for a static CMS

Tags: html, web-development, cms, static-content

I would like to have a static CMS, but I need a web interface for the editor. The editor can be a php/python/ruby app hosted off my computer for when I need to edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not a great deal of web based interfaces to choose from for static designs but you can try:

- [GP Easy](http://gpeasy.com/)
- [Pulse CMS](http://pulsecms.com/)

I don't have a lot of experience using the above but I have adopted methods using WYSIWYG editors on static pages which basically does the same without fancy control panels. You can read more about this below.

Additional you can might want to interment your own WYSIWYG editors which can basically edit static files online by just incorporating 'Edit' Buttons on page (Can do securely with authentication but requires some scripting).

You can find a truck load of [WYSIWYG editors](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/44455/dynamic-content-editor/44462#44462) links on this site on an answer I left a while back.

Comment: Thanks, I might end up making my own, seeing as so many are the same Markdown/Yaml site engines.